# VLC doesn't play audio on Windows 11, says Channels: Unknown-chan-mask

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

**[Edit]** It's probably Windows11 - Windows 10 works fine!

I have a number of mp4 files which used to play fine about a year ago, but now:

- Some play with no sound. Looking in codec info, I see `Channels: Unknown-chan-mask`
- Some still play fine. Their codec info says `Channels: 3F2R/LFE`

Notes:

- I thought this was due to VLC version (I use the current 3.0.17.4), but I installed older versions all the way back to 3.0.0 and still the same issue
- I tried setting VLC stereo to mono/original/stereo/headphone - same thing.
- I run Windows 11 Version 21H2 (22000.739). Audio is `Intel Display Audio HDMI`, driver version 10.27.0.12, driver date 21/11/2021

  - **[Edit]** The same file does play on a different machine, which runs Windows 10 Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1766), with both `Realtek High Definition Audio` driver version 6.0.1.8010, and also `Intel Display Audio HDMI`, driver version 10.27.0.12

Comment: Try another player, e.g., MPC-HC (https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases) or Windows Media Player. If those files won't play in those apps, either they're damaged or a codec was changed or deleted. Ther are sites with codecs, e.g., https://www.videohelp.com/software/sections/codec-packs , **but check that those you plan to install are not malware or adware.**

Comment: MPC-HC plays these fine . I guess I'll switch to it, although it's missing default subtitle encoding settings

Comment: Now that you've proved that the files are indeed playable, and not damaged, I'd suggest now uninstalling VLC, then downloading the latest version from videolan.org: https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html , since I haven't found a file MPC-HC can play that VLC can't, or *vice versa*, Please let me know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I uninstalled+re-installed latest VLC - `vlc-3.0.17.4-win32.exe` - and still no sound. However, I tested on a different machine and I do get sound with the exact same file and VLC! Main difference is - working machine is Windows 10, borked machine is Win11.

Comment: You've narrowed down the causes to something on the Windows 11 PC, whether due to a missing codec, or a Windows 11 incompatibility, You might try DISm and SFC to repair Windows (https://www.ubackup.com/windows-11/repair-windows-11-command-prompt-8523.html), but at least you can use MPC-HC to play those problematic files.